# Growth Rate of the 2nd Chebyshev function

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions, chebyshev-function

What is the growth rate of the 2nd Chebyshev function i.e. $Ψ(x)$

where $Ψ(x)$ $=$ $ln(lcm(1, 2, ... , x)$

**$ln$** denotes the natural logarithm and **$lcm(1, 2, ... , x)$** refers to the lowest common multiple of all integers from 1 to x or alternatively we can say LCM of first x integers.

More specifically I am working on an inequality so I want the growth rate of the function
$F(x)$ $=$ $| Ψ(x) - x |$

Growth rate can be big O or little o notation or simply the degree of growth.

Source:
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function
[2] https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html

Note - I have tried to search for it on the internet including on MSE but could not find any relevant information. I don't have much experience in this field, just asking out of curiosity, thus sorry and thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many upper bounds of your $F(x)$ in the wikipedia page. Aren't those working for your inequality?

Comment: No Sir, actually my approach of proving the inequality is to show that F(x) grows slower than another function G(x) thereby showing that F(x) < G(x), combined with graphical evidence. So I want the growth rate of the functions or atleast the comparison regarding which function dominates and grows faster. I don't think if (upper) bounds can help in some way. Please guide me if possible, thanks.

Comment: So the upper bounds for $F$ in the wiki are all greater than your $G$? If that is the case, it will be tough.

Comment: Sir if you can kindly help me and provide the bounds (especially lower bound) of $g(x)$ $=$ $sqrt(x) * ln(x) * ln(x)$ where ln denotes the natural logarithm, then it would be highly helpful. Because I acknowledge and appreciate your idea of using bounds to prove the inequality. If I get the lower bound, then *maybe* that will be enough to prove the inequality.

Comment: That is the tough case. Only under Riemann Hypothesis we can reach this bound.